# How Kylin store data in Hbase?

Tags: apache, hbase, storage, kylin

Just wanted to understand How kylin Store data in Hbase ?

Eg. I have 1 fact - having 3 column (Dim1.A,Dim2.B,C cal) 2 Dims- Dim 1 (A,Desc), Dim2 (B,Desc) i have 4 distinct records in facts and same 4 records properly exits in Dim1 and Dim2. Kindly help me to understand how many combination this will create in Hbase ? Any leads will be great help !

Thanks,
Rahul S

Answer (score 1):

HBase store data in cube format,Through kylin you can have cubes upto 63 dimensions. A cube has dimensions and measures. you can read more on data cubes from here https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28530/data-cube   additional info - when storing cubes on HBase kylin encrypts them so you cannot access the HBase cubes directly. you  have to go through Kylin.